# does apt-mark hold prevent updates to package dependencies?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dependencies

I have an old package on an old system, and I want to upgrade my OS.
Getting the specific package to work on newer systems might be possible, but I don't want to mess with it right now, I still want to use it. When I tried on Ubuntu 23.04, I entered into the dependency nightmare.

Anyway, does `#apt-mark hold <package>`
hold the dependencies for the package as well as the package?
Does apt-mark hold do anything to prevent package breaking? or does it only prevent updates to the specific package?

Comment: well, I went on and tried it, now I regret it. The program "works" but the fonts used in the windows are evidently unknown, and everything shows up as rectangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `apt-mark hold X` also hold the dependencies?

It sometimes does due to the nature of apt dependency logic: When package X depends upon specific versions of Y and Z, then Y and Z **might** be blocked from upgrading.

- Example: If X depends upon Y < 2.0, then Y will be blocked from upgrading from 1.8 to 2.0.

It's not a separate "hold". The usable versions if Y and Z are specified in the X control file. You can see them by looking at `apt show X`.

- Example for the `hello` package: The `libc6` dependency must be version 2.34 or higher.

  ```
  $ apt show hello | grep Depends
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34)
  ```

The nightmare typically occurs when **other** software also using Y requires newer versions.

- Example: W also depends upon Y. A new version of W depends upon Y > 2.0 in order to use a feature of Y introduced in 2.0. Y blocked below 2.0 means that W is also required to remain at a older version where Y 1.8 is acceptable.

  This confuses users: W does not seem related to X. But they are...through the shared dependency.